# Add a starting value to an Apex:Variable in a Apex:repeat Table

Tags: repeat, apex-variable

I have created a simple table of data in a VF page, which uses Apex:Repeat to list records.

There is a column that contains a cumulative amount, by way of apex:variable. The cumulative amount works fine and repeats, however i need to add a starting amount (currentRecord.Opening_Balance__c) at the top of the column, which the first record in the list uses as a opening amount.

The issue is, adding the variable to the first record amount, and not to every record amount thereafter.

[image: Requirement]

The table on the left is what i am trying to achieve. The table on the right is what I have currently, without applying the "Opening Balance" variable.

I haven't seen this applied elsewhere, so any thoughts would be appreciated...

APEX:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="records" styleClass="panel">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:left">Date</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">Transaction Details</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">Withdrawals</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">Deposits</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">Balance</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <apex:variable value="{!0}" var="Total"/>
        <apex:variable value="{!currentRecord.Opening_Balance__c}" var="open"/>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><b>Opening Balance</b></td>
                <td><b>{!currentRecord.Opening_Balance__c}</b></td>
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!remittanceAdvice}" var="re" >
            <tr>
                <td><apex:outputfield value="{!re.Date__c}"/></td>
                <td>{!re.Account__r.name}</td>
                <td>{!re.Remittance_Total_Debit__c}</td>
                <td>{!re.Remittance_Total_Credit__c}</td>
                    <apex:variable var="Total" value="{!Total - re.Remittance_Total_Debit__c + re.Remittance_Total_Credit__c }"/>
                <td>{!Total}</td>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><b>Closing Balance</b></td>
                <td><b>{!currentRecord.Closing_Balance__c}</b></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: You have already added this `<apex:variable value="{!currentRecord.Opening_Balance__c}" var="open"/>` what else you want to add here?

Comment: Tushar, the variable is there, however i cant use it. If i apply to the total in the repeat list, it will iterate over every record.

Comment: You can add that before the repeat.

Comment: Thats correct, but the first record amount of the repeat will ignore it in the cumulative total

Comment: Sorry but I am not clear on your requirement here. May be if you can explain or someone else might able to help you here.

Comment: Will this not work for you <apex:variable value="{!currentRecord.Opening_Balance__c}" var="Total"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos to Tushar (see comments).

Changing the variable (var) worked.

`<apex:variable value="{!currentRecord.Opening_Balance__c}" var="open"/>`

to

```
<apex:variable value="{!currentRecord.Opening_Balance__c}" var="total"/>
```